# "Package edu.princeton.cs.algs4 does not exist" when running a Java Program on Command Prompt

Tags: java, netbeans, cmd

I'm studying Algorithms and use this site to learn: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/

Also currently use its libs to run sample code

> algs4.jar

I create a class named UFClient in NetBeans IDE under the default package:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceLPe.png)

UFClient's code:

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package dsasample;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Dell
 */
public class UFClient {
    public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    int N = StdIn.readInt();
    UF uf = new UF(N);
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
    {
        int p = StdIn.readInt();
        int q = StdIn.readInt();
        if (!uf.connected(p, q))
        {
            uf.union(p, q);
            StdOut.println(p + " " + q);
        }
     }
    }
}
```

I execute in Command Prompt using this:

> javac -cp D:\coursera\algs-4.jar;. UFClient.java

But this error

```
D:\Netbean_Proj\DSASample\src\dsasample>javac -cp D:\coursera\algs-4.jar;. UFClient.java
UFClient.java:7: error: package edu.princeton.cs.algs4 does not exist
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*;
^
UFClient.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    int N = StdIn.readInt();
            ^
  symbol:   variable StdIn
  location: class UFClient
UFClient.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    UF uf = new UF(N);
    ^
  symbol:   class UF
  location: class UFClient
UFClient.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    UF uf = new UF(N);
                ^
  symbol:   class UF
  location: class UFClient
UFClient.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
            ^
  symbol:   variable StdIn
  location: class UFClient
UFClient.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        int p = StdIn.readInt();
                ^
  symbol:   variable StdIn
  location: class UFClient
UFClient.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        int q = StdIn.readInt();
                ^
  symbol:   variable StdIn
  location: class UFClient
UFClient.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
            StdOut.println(p + " " + q);
            ^
  symbol:   variable StdOut
  location: class UFClient
8 errors

D:\Netbean_Proj\DSASample\src\dsasample>
```

What's wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: The Command Prompt, _[tag:cmd]_, isn't returning any error, the error is clearly being returned by [tag:java], `cmd.exe` is simply acting as an interface.

Comment: I got it so what's the problem here?

Comment: You're using the [[tag:cmd]] tag for no reason, or using it because you think that `cmd.exe` is part of the problem, _and for that, you need to provide debugging information_. You code appears to use `edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*`, but it does not seem to provide the location, or stipulate what the current directory is, in order to have that relative to a known location. Your Command Prompt output shows that your current directory, in this specific case, is `D:\Netbean_Proj\DSASample\src\dsasample`, so I'd assume it is looking for the `edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*` files there, is that where they are?

Comment: It works now. Sorry for my mad typing